# How to send plus operator in url in java

Tags: java, android

I am fetching data from server in my project. In some condition there is a need to send + operator in url with parameter. How can i send "+" in url with parameter.

here is my url

```
http://www.needsthesupermarket.com/webservice/dp/addCart.php?cart_id=43530&cust_id=13936&pid=11303&qty=1&combination=2 ltr + 1 kg&guest_id=2509245
```

In blank space i replace with `%20`. but problem with + sign. How can i send it in url?

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
%2B

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: You should use a library which performs [URI Templates](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6570). That is the only surefire way to generate URLs like this. And while I have a project which does that, I don't guarantee its compatibility with android. Also, @Blackbelt: `URL*coder` encode/decode form data; this is different from what is {dis,}allowed in a query string.

Comment: that is working.. thanks to all... for reply

Answer (score 1):

```
%26 -> &

%2B -> +
```

You can decode/encode [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Answer (score 0):

You should encode your GET parameters:

```
Uri.encode(someParam)
```

For example if you have some `Map` `paramsGet` with GET parameters:

```
final StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("http://example.com");
String delim = "?";
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : paramsGet.entrySet()) {
    url.append(delim).append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(Uri.encode(entry.getValue()));
    delim = "&";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Encode use**

```
String encodedInput = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(inputText, "UTF-8");
```

**To Decode use**

```
String decodedInput = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(encodedInput, "UTF-8");
```